# Can I have a CSS rule change based on browser?

Tags: html, css, google-chrome

I have a block quote on a project Im working on and I want the text-align to change if the page is being viewed with Chrome. Chrome doesnt seem to recognize text-align-last so Id rather just change all the alignment to text-align:center; if being viewed with Chrome.

If its being looked at with another browser I want the rules to be text-align: justify; text-align-last: center;.

Is there a way to do this?

Comment: From the user agent, you can usually tell the type of browser being used

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[Browser sniffing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Browser_sniffing) is bad, you should use [feature detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_%28web_development%29) instead.

In this case, you can use [`@supports`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/@supports):

```css
#target {
  text-align: center;
}
@supports (-moz-text-align-last: center) or (text-align-last: center) {
  #target {
    text-align: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: center;
    text-align-last: center
  }
}
```

```css
#target {
  text-align: center;
}
@supports (-moz-text-align-last: center) or (text-align-last: center) {
  #target {
    text-align: justify;
    -moz-text-align-last: center;
    text-align-last: center
  }
}
```

```html
<div id="target">Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Donec a diam lectus. Sed sit amet ipsum mauris. Maecenas congue ligula ac quam viverra nec consectetur ante hendrerit. Donec et mollis dolor. Praesent et diam eget libero egestas mattis sit amet vitae augue. Nam tincidunt congue enim, ut porta lorem lacinia consectetur. Donec ut libero sed arcu vehicula ultricies a non tortor. Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Aenean ut gravida lorem. Ut turpis felis, pulvinar a semper sed, adipiscing id dolor. Pellentesque auctor nisi id magna consequat sagittis. Curabitur dapibus enim sit amet elit pharetra tincidunt feugiat nisl imperdiet. Ut convallis libero in urna ultrices accumsan. Donec sed odio eros. Donec viverra mi quis quam pulvinar at malesuada arcu rhoncus. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. In rutrum accumsan ultricies. Mauris vitae nisi at sem facilisis semper ac in est.</div>
```

Comment: Is @supports a selector? Is there a name for this sort of technique?

Comment: `@supports` is an [at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/CSS/At-rule), specifically a [conditional-group at-rule](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/At-rule#Conditional_Group_Rules). The technique is called [feature detection](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Feature_detection_%28web_development%29).

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can change the css style using JavaScript (JQuery makes it easier). JavaScript can also detect what browser is being used so you can use an if statement to change the css code based on the browser:

```
if($.browser.chrome) {}
```

Example of changing css code with JQuery:

```
$("p").css("align", "right");
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use a CSS only Hack to detect Chrome you can use the following:

```
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0)
{ 
    #element { properties:value; } 
}
```

More browser specific hacks can be found here:

https://css-tricks.com/snippets/css/browser-specific-hacks/

For historical purposes:

```
/***** Selector Hacks ******/

/* IE6 and below */
* html #uno  { color: red }

/* IE7 */
*:first-child+html #dos { color: red } 

/* IE7, FF, Saf, Opera  */
html>body #tres { color: red }

/* IE8, FF, Saf, Opera (Everything but IE 6,7) */
html>/**/body #cuatro { color: red }

/* Opera 9.27 and below, safari 2 */
html:first-child #cinco { color: red }

/* Safari 2-3 */
html[xmlns*=""] body:last-child #seis { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:nth-of-type(1) #siete { color: red }

/* safari 3+, chrome 1+, opera9+, ff 3.5+ */
body:first-of-type #ocho {  color: red }

/* saf3+, chrome1+ */
@media screen and (-webkit-min-device-pixel-ratio:0) {
 #diez  { color: red  }
}

/* iPhone / mobile webkit */
@media screen and (max-device-width: 480px) {
 #veintiseis { color: red  }
}

/* Safari 2 - 3.1 */
html[xmlns*=""]:root #trece  { color: red  }

/* Safari 2 - 3.1, Opera 9.25 */
*|html[xmlns*=""] #catorce { color: red  }

/* Everything but IE6-8 */
:root *> #quince { color: red  }

/* IE7 */
*+html #dieciocho {  color: red }

/* Firefox only. 1+ */
#veinticuatro,  x:-moz-any-link  { color: red }

/* Firefox 3.0+ */
#veinticinco,  x:-moz-any-link, x:default  { color: red  }
```